# Klingon science vessel: battles against ignorance, spoils of knowledge

Tags: star-trek, klingon

I found the following on [TV tropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/KlingonScientistsGetNoRespect):

> In one episode of DS9 we heard a snippet of a Klingon science vessel's log where the captain spoke of winning battles against ignorance, and bringing home vast spoils in the form of new knowledge.

Does anybody know what episode this refers to? The [Science Vessel](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Science_vessel) page on Memory Alpha makes no mention of Klingon science vessels, and google is not much help either.

Comment: I tried to find this a while ago and failed. I think it's someone's headcanon.

Comment: The closest thing I could think of is DS9: Dramatis Personae, but that doesn't quite fit.

Comment: Yes, in the [Dramatis Personae transcript](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/418.htm) there was this exchange: *KIRA: The Klingon said victory just before he died. I wonder what he meant. 
DAX: According to Klingon High Command, the Toh'Kaht was in the Gamma quadrant on a routine bio-survey mission, 
O'BRIEN: Victory during a bio-survey?* It's possible the TV Tropes editor misremembered "victory during a bio-survey" as actually talking about victory in science, but it turned out the Klingons had discovered some alien technology that caused them to battle one another.

Comment: I seem to recall an episode of *Enterprise* where an elderly Klingon (lawyer? scientist?) spoke at some length on how Kilgons used to value more than just war and battle glory, but the warrior culture kind of took over within the last few generations.

Comment: @joe - This is Ent: Judgement; "*KOLOS: My father was a teacher. My mother, a biologist at the university. They encouraged me to take up the law. Now all young people want to do is take up weapons as soon as they can hold them. They're told there's honour in victory, any victory. What honour is there in a victory over a weaker opponent? Had Duras destroyed that ship he would have been lauded as a hero of the Empire for murdering helpless refugees. We were a great society not so long ago, when honour was earned through integrity and acts of true courage, not senseless bloodshed."*

Comment: @Richard: That's it. Thanks!

Comment: @Richard Yet more evidence that *Enterprise* rocked. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there is only one instance where the log of a Klingon ship is reconstructed, in DS9: Dramatic Personae. At no point do the words ascribed to them (about klingon scientists 'winning battles against ignorance' or carrying off 'spoils' in the form of knowledge) appear in *any* episode of any Trek series.

There are, however some script excerpts that might have been mis-remembered by the Tropes page's author.

- **In DS9: [Dramatic Personae](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/418.txt), the following exchange appears.**

> **KIRA:** *The Klingon said "victory" before he died.  I wonder what he meant.*
>
> **DAX:** *According to the Klingon high command, the Toh'Kaht was in the gamma quadrant on a routine bio-survey mission...*
>
> **O'BRIEN:** *"Victory"... during a bio-survey... ?*
>
> A beat as everyone considers this.

- **and possibly this speech from Enterprise: [Judgement](http://www.chakoteya.net/Enterprise/45.htm)**

> **KOLOS:** *My father was a teacher. My mother, a biologist at the university. They encouraged me to take up the law. Now all young
>   people want to do is take up weapons as soon as they can hold them.
>   They're told there's honour in victory, any victory. What honour is
>   there in a victory over a weaker opponent? Had Duras destroyed that
>   ship he would have been lauded as a hero of the Empire for murdering
>   helpless refugees. **We were a great society not so long ago, when
>   honour was earned through integrity and acts of true courage, not
>   senseless bloodshed***